# App.get('router').send causing this error Uncaught TypeError: Cannot redefine property: __ember1346884664897

Tags: ember.js, ember-old-router

Anyone have any ideas why I'm getting this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot redefine property: __ember1346884664897
```

when calling:

```
App.get('router').send('tags')
```

I'm making the call from one of my views, the router is in the correct state, and as far as I can tell I'm doing everything by the book.

Would really appreciate any ideas...

Created a gist that might help explain things a little better. https://gist.github.com/3647288

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`App.router.send('something')` will look for a function named `something` in your current state, but you are trying to use route name there. You should have something like `showTags` in you router and use `App.router.send('showTags')`.

Head to docs http://docs.emberjs.com/#doc=Ember.Router&src=false and look at the part `Transitions Between States`

Comment: Amazing! Thanks so much for helping me out, your solution worked like a treat. It was so obvious once I read your comment, can't believe I missed it. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem when I named an action and a state the same way. Perhaps you have the same thing now.